# Does nesting in an empty else yield overhead?

Tags: java, performance

Example 1:

```
if(some statement)
   .... //irrelevant code
else
   if(other statement)
      .....
   else
      .....
```

Example 2:

```
if(some statement)
   .... //irrelevant code
else if(other statement)
   ....
else
   ....
```

In my case, I would prefer to use example 1 to show that the nested if statements are related.

Is example 1 less efficient then example 2?

Comment: Unless you have measured a performance difference which is impacting your application, you should generally assume you don't have a performance problem.  In this case there is no difference, the use of whitespace or formatting make no difference to performance. Even if there was a small difference, it is unlikely to change your choice as to which is clearer to read.

Comment: I would always keep in mind that the first `if(some statement)` should contain the most possible true condition, since the other checks are not called then. The other answers here stated the question about readability.

Comment: They're exactly the same, you just put the if on the next line. Also, an else if is the same thing as a nested if else because it only executes the next statement, which happens to be the if. You could see this yourself by comparing the bytecode for each.

Comment: The above two examples are identical, save for formatting.  They will behave exactly the same.  (Of course, throw in some `{}` characters here and there and you can make them quite different.)

Comment: (I would never code the first example without using `{}` -- You should never "nest" without `{}` both because of the visual cues and because you can introduce subtle bugs.)

Comment: Subtle bugs, indeed. That parsing ambiguity would be a nightmare to notice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two codes are the same as this one:

```
if(some statement) .... else if(other statement) else
```

Performance has nothing to do with this, this is exactly the same code (The same *bytecode* will be generated), whereas readability does something to do with this, I prefer the first.

I advise you to have curly brackets even for one-line statements inside `if` and `else` blocks:

```
if(something) {
   doSomething();
} else if(something2()) {
   doSomething2();
} else {
   doSomething3();
}
```

Comment: +1 though I prefer the second.  I prefer to only use nesting when it makes a difference, otherwise you might assume that nesting matters in cases where it doesn't.  Again, I don't use redundant `{ }` instead I use the code formatter in my IDE ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey Sometimes I don't either, but I always advise people to have `{ }` since this might help beginners in future "indentation bugs" :)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I violently disagree on omitting the `{}`.  It is incredibly easy to introduce a bug when you do that -- not immediately but when you edit the code.  And, to my mind, the primary criterion for any coding style issue is minimizing bugs.

Comment: @HotLicks I believe you should use the tools you have available, and if you use your IDE correctly and its formatting, the { } are just redundant.  You will introduce more problems by not using standard formatting than you can save by using { }

Comment: I use an IDE for most of my programming, yet even I (yes, me) have made the mistake of sticking a second statement into an if/else without `{}`.  Done it two or three times, and at least once it took more than a minute to figure out.  Sometimes it produces a syntax error, sometimes the compiler happily compiles incorrect code.